# How to reduce header size through browser in all api request?

Tags: google-chrome, postman, microsoft-edge, brave

I am trying to make some API calls from my browser (Chrome or Brave) , but I noticed that the browser automatically adds some headers to my requests which makes every API not working, Giving such error in postman (if i add whole header sent through browser CURL) and browser console:

`HTTP Status 400 – Bad Request`
`POST https://uat-example.com:31554/fetchPendingActionsCount?pageNumber=1&pageSize=10&categoryPurpose=IBFT&fromRecordedDate=2023-10-31&toRecordedDate=2023-11-01 net::ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED`

While If i try in postman , removing headers Such as :

- authority
- accept
- accept-language
- sec-fetch-dest
- sec-fetch-mode
- sec-gpc
- user-agent

I found that API would successfully hit through postman .

Is there any way not to send header automatically through browser or manipulate , what is being sent to every requests.

Thank you for your help :) .

Comment: That seems unexpected. I think the issue is more to do with the contents of the headers and not the total length. Especially given the 400 error implies that the request is malformed in some way.